# Как спарсить подсказки навигации с яндекс карт

Tags: яндекс-карты

Нужно получать данные о маршруте(поворот направо, через 300 метров налево) из приложения яндекс карт для дальнейшей отправки на дополнительный экран. Подскажите, какую-нибудь документацию в данном направлении.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: можно предположить, что вам надо обращаться в яндекс и готовить кучу денег за доступ к соответствующему api. разработка, поддержка, работа всей соответствующей инфраструктуры — это ж огромные деньги, которые им надо «отбивать».